# Deleting a non-owned dynamic array through a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-data, delete-operator

I'm relatively novice when it comes to C++ as I was weened on Java for much of my undergraduate curriculum (tis a shame). Memory management has been a hassle, but I've purchased a number books on ansi C and C++. I've poked around the related questions, but couldn't find one that matched this particular criteria. Maybe it's so obvious nobody mentions it?

This question has been bugging me, but I feel as if there's a conceptual point I'm not utilizing.

Suppose:

```
char original[56];
cstr[0] = 'a';
cstr[1] = 'b';
cstr[2] = 'c';
cstr[3] = 'd';
cstr[4] = 'e';
cstr[5] = '\0';
char *shaved = shavecstr(cstr); 
// various operations, calls //
delete[] shaved;
```

Where,

```
char* shavecstr(char* cstr) 
{
    size_t len = strlen(cstr);
    char* ncstr = new char[len];
    strcpy(ncstr,cstr);
    return ncstr;
}
```

In that the whole point is to have 'original' be a buffer that fills with characters and routinely has its copy shaved and used elsewhere.

To clarify, original is filled via `std::gets(char* buff)`, `std::getline(char* buff, buff_sz)`, `std::read(char* buff, buff_sz)`, or any in-place filling input reader. To 'shave' a string, it's basically truncated down eliminating the unused array space.

The error is a heap allocation error, and segs on the `delete[]`.

To prevent leaks, I want to free up the memory held by 'shaved' to be used again after it passes through some arguments. There is probably a good reason for why this is restricted, but there should be some way to free the memory as by this configuration, there is no way to access the original owner (pointer) of the data.

Comment: Where is your `original` buffer being used?  Is `cstr` supposed to be `original`?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Is there a compiler error?  Other than the variable names being wrong, and me not understanding what you are trying to accomplish with "shaving", what is the problem exactly?  If you are serious about using C++, you should use `std::string` rather than `char*`, and just avoid this whole memory management mess altogether.

Comment: And is cstrn supposed to be cstr?

Comment: also you are deleting cstrn array which is not defined anywhere

Comment: Oh yeah, you are forgetting to allocate space for the null terminator, so `strcpy` is writing off the end of your array.  If you must use C style strings, prefer `strncpy`.

Comment: cstrn isn't declared/defined/assigned anywhere. I can't see this compiling...If you want to delete(free) the memory pointed to by "shaved", then it should be fine. When you allocate an array on the heap using new, the array knows how big it is (I don't think the standard specifies HOW it must do it, just that it should), so that delete[] can work properly.

Comment: Can you clarify that part: *"to be used again after it passes through some arguments"*

Comment: Ah, sorry about the edits, I'm not familiar with the interface. The code here is a shallow rewrite so the variables have generic names which I somehow ended up mixing.
The primary error is a Heap corruption which i'm betting is on the new.

I can't see how this isn't valid as shavecstr returns the address to the memory allocated by ncstr and stores it in shaved where it should be able to delete[].

Comment: Ah, turns out, it was the fault of my complier! never again will I use VS for C++. I suppose I need to find a new IDE to debug with.

Used gcc and I've had no issues since.

Comment: Don't blame the compiler.  There is a reason your code is failing.  Most likely the memory corruption due to going off the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would replace `original` by `cstr`, otherwise the code won't compile as `cstr` is not declared.

The error here is that the size of the allocated array is too small. You want `char* ncstr = new char[len+1];` to account for the terminating `\0`.

Also, if you delete `shaved` right after the function returns, there is no point in calling the function...

[*] To go a bit deeper, the memory used for `cstr` will be released when the containing function returns. Usually such static strings are placed in constants that live for the entire duration of the application. For example, you could have `const char* cstr="abcde";` outside all your functions. Then you can pass this string around without having to dynamically allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to use `cstr` instead of `cstrn`...

You should not be deleting `cstr`.  You should be deleting `shaved`.

You only `delete` the memory that was allocated with `new`.  And `delete[]` memory that was allocated with `new[]`.

`shaved` is simply a variable that holds a memory address.  You pass that memory address to `delete[]` to get rid of the memory.  `shaved` holds the memory address of the memory that was allocated with `new[]`.